# Swap css classes inside every Bootstrap row

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, mixins, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-sass

Please find the below code,

```
$scope.datas = [{name:'AB', age:1}, {name:'BC', age:2}, 
{name:'CD', age:3}, {name:'EF', age:4}, {name:'GH', age:5}, 
{name:'IJ', age:6}]

<div ng-repeat="data in datas" class="col-xs-6">
  <span>{{data.name}}</span>
  <span>{{data.age}}</span>
</div>

 .red{
   background-color: red;
  }

.green{
 background-color: green;
}
```

like

```
  red    green
  green  red
  red    green
```

I want to use these(red, green) classes to swap every bootstrap rows. How can we achieve this?

Comment: You should be using `:nth-child` for this, rather than extra classes (and classes with such terrible names on top of that ...) https://jsfiddle.net/j24yk5L5/

Comment: @CBroe, thanks its working perfectly without css classes ,:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `:nth-child` for this, rather than extra classes.

```
div {
  /* formatting for the “normal” elements goes here (red)
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

div:nth-child(4n+2),  // select every 2nd
div:nth-child(4n+3) { // and 3rd out of each “group” of 4 elements
  /* formatting for the “special” elements, based on their position */
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

A simple fiddle demonstrating the principle: https://jsfiddle.net/j24yk5L5/

Comment: Actually I&#39;m using the bg color instead of outline property, its working fine. Thanks☺

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas" class="col-xs-6" ng-class="$index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'">
    <span>{{data.name}}</span>
    <span>{{data.age}}</span>
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
.even span:nth-child(even),
.odd span:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: red;
}
.even span:nth-child(odd),
.odd span:nth-child(even){
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Nope, if i could use, cant get the above i mentioned one.

Comment: @Jeyabalan, sorry, misinterpreted the question, have made an edit

Comment: can we swap the css class for the whole div, not in each span tag?